# Random Background Music Loop PHP

Tags: php

on a particular website I currently have a script that randomises the background music that is played each time the website is accessed. It grabs the file randomly from a sound folder and plays. Everything works great.

**PHP**

```
$songs = glob('snd/*.*');
```

**HTML**

```
<embed src="swf/player.swf" id="radioplayer" name="radioplayer" quality="medium" allowScriptAccess="always" width="1" height="1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" FlashVars="file=<?php echo $song; ?>&volume=10&start=0&duration=0&autostart=true&controlbar=none&dock=false&icons=false&loop=1">
```

However, I would like to expand this a little more.

It is used as a loading screen for a gameserver which requires custom files to be downloaded to the client. Once the song finishes, it's just silence. I'm wondering: is it possible that when the song is finished a new song is selected randomly, like how it was the first time, and then played? The only thing is, even though I want the selection to be random I do not want it to play the song that was just played.

Hopefully this is possible and thanks in advance.

**Note**

It uses a flash player to play the songs, as you can see. If this is not a viable method of playing the songs with my request above I'm welcome to alternative methods, provided I can control the volume of the audio that plays.

*Edit*

To try and kill two birds with one stone, the webpage's background image also changes depending on which map the server is currently using. I do not have images for each map I add as I add more all the time, would it be possible to set the background to a default image instead of it just being blank?

Comment: Use a different flash player that supports playlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im doing this in javacript, you could just add the song as a string creating the Audio object!
    Example

```
 var titleTheme = new Audio("PUT_RANDOM_SONG_HERE");
```

Real World
***The magic and what you are looking for is to add an event listener too the event "ended".***

```
var titleTheme = new Audio("AUDIO/tmnt.mp3");

//Start up with this
titleTheme.play();

// Events _________________________________________________ 
// BIND TITLE THEME ENDED
titleTheme.addEventListener('ended',endings);
function endings()
{
 titleTheme.play();
}
```

Things to know, **not all browsers play all the fileformats**. So you will have to be able to supply audio as per browser.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more here?

Comment: @JakeGriffin okay I have added an example! remember I did my implentation in javascript. As an alternative method. Got it? Added the eventbinding thing also.

Comment: I apologise but I don't quite follow. I am not that knowledgeable on the subject. (Sorry to sound like an idiot.)

Comment: @JakeGriffin You said you could take an alternative solution, the one I provided is in javascript. Ok so what i do first is I create an Audio in this case titleTheme the object I feed this just like you feed the flash player with a song(path_to_one). Then I use the play method which the audio object has. The music will start to play, next thing is that I set an eventlistener to the titletheme object which listens for when the song has ended. this will start the song all over again, using the play method that the object has.

Comment: @Chris The only thing is when the first song finishes it plays the same song when it ends - I want it to randomly choose another song to play when it's done, is that possible?

Comment: @Chris Yes you could load an array with your songs fill the array with your audio objects. Inside the function that goes of when the songs ends, create a random number not higher than your arraylength. Then load that.